# Getting a row count on joined tables using NHibernate

Tags: asp.net, nhibernate, nhibernate-criteria

I have a Many-To-Many relationship consisting of the following 3 tables (non relevant fields removed from brevity), in that an advert may be assigned multiple tags, and a tag can be assigned to multiple adverts.

**Adverts**

```
(PK) Id
```

**AdvertsTags**

```
(FK) AdvertId
(FK) TagId
```

**Tags**

```
(PK) Id
```

I want to create an NHibernate query that counts how many Adverts are assigned a specific Tag (i.e. a specific TagId).

In normal sql I would do something along the lines of:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM Adverts A
JOIN AdvertsTags AT ON A.Id = AT.AdvertId
WHERE AT.TagId = @tagId
```

The property names of my `Advert` and `Tag` models are as per the field names in the tables shown above.

I don't know what would be the recommended way of doing this using NHibernate?

Comment: Assuming your objects are mapped properly, is there a reason you can't  retrieve tag by Id and then use Tag.Adverts.Count?

Comment: I thought that would have performance implications, retrieving an entire list of all adverts only to then do a count on it (when I don't have a need for the full list of ads assigned to a given tag, just a count - When I need a list of ads assigned to a tag, I will have paging methods to return only x rows at a time that I need).

Comment: If I understand NHibernate implementation correctly, lazy loading the collection and calling Count() on it should NOT result in storing all items in memory. If you already have a DB up and running, you can check the query that nhibernate generates. Of course, it may not be relevant anymore, considering you already have an accepted answer :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this would help:

```
var count = session
    .CreateCriteria(typeof(Advert))
    .SetProjection(Projections.RowCount())
    .CreateCriteria("Tags")
    .Add(Expression.Eq("TagId", tagId)
    .UniqueResult<long>();
```

More info here: http://www.nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#querycriteria-associations